# Fitting a line with gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I am trying to fit a line to a couple of points using gradient descent. I am no expert on this and tried to write down the mathematical algorithm for it in python. It runs for a couple of iterations, but my predictions seem to explode at some point. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mean_squared_error(n, A, b, m, c):
    e = 0
    for i in range(n):
        e += (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)) ** 2   
    return e/n

def der_wrt_m(n,A,b,m,c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        d += (2 * (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)) * (-A[i]))
    return d/n

def der_wrt_c(n,A,b,m,c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        d += (2 * (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)))
    return d/n

def update(n,A,b,m,c,descent_rate):
    return descent_rate * der_wrt_m(n,A,b,m,c)), descent_rate * der_wrt_c(n,A,b,m,c))

A = np.array(((0,1),
             (1,1),
             (2,1),
             (3,1)))
x = A.T[0]
b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin=2 ).T
y = b.reshape(4)

def descent(x,y):
    m = 0
    c = 0

    descent_rate = 0.00001
    iterations = 100

    n = len(x)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
    prediction = 0
    for itr in range(iterations):
        print(m,c)
        prediction = prediction + m * x + c
        m,c = update(n,x,y,m,c,descent_rate)

    plt.plot(u, u * m + c, '-')   


descent(x,y)
```

And that's my output:

```
0 0
19.25 -10.5
-71335.1953125 24625.9453125
5593771382944640.0 -2166081169939480.2
-2.542705027685638e+48 9.692684648057364e+47
2.40856742196228e+146 -9.202614421953049e+145
-inf inf
nan nan
nan nan
nan nan
nan nan
nan nan
nan nan
etc...
```

---

Update: The values aren't exploding anymore, but it's still not converging in a nice manner:

```
# We could also solve it using gradient descent
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mean_squared_error(n, A, b, m, c):
    e = 0
    for i in range(n):
        e += ((b[i] - (m * A[i] + c)) ** 2)   
    #print("mse:",e/n)
    return e/n

def der_wrt_m(n,A,b,m,c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        # d += (2 * (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)) * (-A[i]))
        d += (A[i] * (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)))
    #print("Dm",-2 * d/n)
    return (-2 * d/n)

def der_wrt_c(n,A,b,m,c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        d += (2 * (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)))
    #print("Dc",d/n)
    return d/n

def update(n,A,b,m,c, descent_rate):
    return (m - descent_rate * der_wrt_m(n,A,b,m,c)),(c - descent_rate * der_wrt_c(n,A,b,m,c))

A = np.array(((0,1),
             (1,1),
             (2,1),
             (3,1)))
x = A.T[0]
b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin=2 ).T
y = b.reshape(4)

def descent(x,y):
    m = 0
    c = 0

    descent_rate = 0.0001
    iterations = 10000

    n = len(x)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
    prediction = 0
    for itr in range(iterations):
        prediction = prediction + m * x + c
        m,c = update(n,x,y,m,c,descent_rate)
        loss = mean_squared_error(n, A, b, m, c)

    print(loss)
    print(m,c)
    plt.plot(u, u * m + c, '-')    

descent(x,y)
```

And now the graph looks like this after about 10000 iterations with a learning rate of 0.0001:

```
[4.10833186 5.21468937]
1.503547594304175 -1.9947003678083184
```

[image: gradient descent]

Whereas the least square fit shows something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your update function, you should subtract calculated gradients from current m and c

```
def update(n,A,b,m,c,descent_rate):
    return m - (descent_rate * der_wrt_m(n,A,b,m,c)), c - (descent_rate * der_wrt_c(n,A,b,m,c))
```

Update: Here is the working version. I got rid of A matrix after obtaining x,y since it confuses me =). For example in your gradient calculations you have an expression `d += (A[i] * (b[i] - (m*A[i] + c)))` but it should be `d += (x[i] * (b[i] - (m*x[i] + c)))` since x[i] gives you a single element whereas A[i] gives you a list.

Also you forgot a minus sign while calculating derivative with respect to c. If your expression is `(y - (m*x + c))^2)` than derivative with respect to c should be `2 * (-1) * (y - (m*x + c))` since there is a minus in front of c.

```
# We could also solve it using gradient descent
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mean_squared_error(n, x, y, m, c):
    e = 0
    for i in range(n):
        e += (m*x[i]+c - y[i])**2
    e = e/n
    return e/n

def der_wrt_m(n, x, y, m, c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        d += x[i] * (y[i] - (m*x[i] + c))
    d = -2 * d/n
    return d

def der_wrt_c(n, x, y, m, c):
    d = 0
    for i in range(n):
        d += (y[i] - (m*x[i] + c))
    d = -2 * d/n
    return d


def update(n,x,y,m,c, descent_rate):
    return (m - descent_rate * der_wrt_m(n,x,y,m,c)),(c - descent_rate * der_wrt_c(n,x,y,m,c))


A = np.array(((0,1),
             (1,1),
             (2,1),
             (3,1)))
x = A.T[0]
b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin=2 ).T
y = b.reshape(4)

print(x)
print(y)

def descent(x,y):
    m = 0.0
    c = 0.0

    descent_rate = 0.01
    iterations = 10000

    n = len(x)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
    prediction = 0
    for itr in range(iterations):
        prediction = prediction + m * x + c
        m,c = update(n,x,y,m,c,descent_rate)
        loss = mean_squared_error(n, x, y, m, c)
        print(loss)

    print(loss)
    print(m,c)
    plt.plot(u, u * m + c, '-')    
    plt.show()

descent(x,y)
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to what I'm doing in my update function?

Comment: Also I don't understand what your A matrix represents since its different from y.

Comment: Yes I realized that that was wrong when I went over the math again. I tried setting my learning rate to 0.1 but my jupyter notebook gives me an overflow error

Comment: A[0] is basically the x values of my points. I don't know why, but that's how it was given to me, which is kind of... dumb. Also thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @AhmadMoussa Your main problem was in the derivative with respect to c, you forgot a minus sign, also using A[i] instead of x[i] is not correct.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! It fits the line nicely now. Thank you for your assistance. If it isn't too much to ask, how would I go about turning extending this into a polynomial regression? Also I just noticed that the loss converges at some point, is that normal? Or is there a way to reduce it further?

Comment: The approach is basically the same with linear regression, Think about your equation y = m*x + c, change some symbols to y= a*x + b, you actually performed a polynomial regression with degree 1, you have 2 parameters to optimize. For nth degree polynomial regression you have y = a*x^n + b*x^(n-1) ... + CONSTANT, so you have n+1 parameters to optimize. Follow the same procedure you did with linear regression: Calculate gradients with respect to each parameter and update same way. But unlike linear regression your solution might depend on your initial choice (not sure).

Comment: So, if I want to fit a polynomial of n-th degree then I will have to calculate n partial derivatives? And initial choice you mean the starting point? Because I could get stuck in a local minimum? Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: About convergence, for your linear regression you will find your optimal solution or somewhere close to it at some point  (larger degree polynomial regressions may stuck at local minima). Actually what you should (I am just advising this for your regression problem, not a general gradient descent problem ) do is to not use a fixed number of steps but continue gradient descent until the amount of your update is very small like 1e-5, 1e-6.